# Can i prevent the "Shortcuts will continue with your request" message in my Siri custom intent?

Tags: ios, siri, sirishortcuts

I have a custom Siri Shortcuts intent. It works well, but if my task takes too long, for example due to bad network conditions, i get the "shortcuts will continue..." message in some circumstances.

The process isn't killed, my task completes eventually, so this makes it confusing for the end user.

It would be great if there was some way to "ask for more time", or do something similar to the apple watch "tap you when i'm ready".

Can i do anything at all to prevent or change the message?

Comment: Hi @Mathias: did you got any solution for this ?

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not seem possible right now. We implemented a workaround, where we have a short timeout, and rather fail more often than serving up that vague response...